# np.histogram outputs?? - Python

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, mod-python

Trying to understand what kind of output do I get from the *histogram* function.

```
phase = mod(phase,Nper*2*pi)
cl_phase = arange(0,Nper*2*pi+step,step)
c,p = histogram(phase,cl_phase)

while 0 in c:
    step = step*2
    cl_phase = arange(0,Nper*2*pi+step,step)
    c,p = histogram(phase,cl_phase)
```

This is what I am trying to understand.
I dont comprehend the very first line and also the objective of using the histogram function (and the outputs it provides)

Not sure if this is enough for anyone take any sort of conclusion, but anything that you might understand from this would help me a lot to shed some light on this issue!
I also don't understand the argument for the *while loop*. Why is zero being "taken out"?

Thank you in advance!

PS: Nper is the number of periods (in this case it's a wave) I am analysing
Phase is a np.array

Comment: I would suggest using `print()` function to understand what is going in the code, along with `type()` to understand what any variable is. It's possible that `c` is an array in which `0` exists multiple times, so `0 in c` is `True` for few iterations of the loop, and as soon as it becomes `False`, the loop is complete, and doesn't execute the code inside it.

Comment: Also, please update the code. The current code provides little context to the reader e.g., what's the package you are using from which you are importing functions like `mod`, `histogram`, etc? Please create [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that'll help us to solve the issue.